# Set gravity of view children from loop of constraintlayout

Tags: java, android, android-view, textview, android-constraintlayout

when I access children which are dynamically created as `TextView` with a loop of a `ConstraintLayout`, they are returned as `View`, which don't have `setGravity`.

Does anyone know a way to set the gravity of these views (gravity for the `TextView`/child, not the layout)?

```
for (int i = 0;i < constraintLayout.getChildCount();i++) {
    final View child = constraintLayout.getChildAt(i);
    Object tag = child.getTag(R.id.tagId);
    if(tag != null) {
        //child.setGravity(Gravity.START); // Doesn't work...
    } else {} }
```

I didn't see any option for setting `Gravity` through 
`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` or `ConstraintSet` either.

Also, I tried `final TextView child = (TextView) constraintLayout.getChildAt(i);`: However, this resulted in a fatal exception: *java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView*. Note: The children are textviews, not imageviews...

Comment: if(child  instanceof TextView) {  final TextView child = (TextView) constraintLayout.getChildAt(i); }

Comment: @has19 Thank you for your reply. Though I get an error in the if statement, since `child` hasn't been declared yet I think. And even if I do it in two steps by declaring child as a `View`, and then create the if statement for a `TextView` version, for some reason the variable isn't accessible. ex: `if(child instanceof TextView) {final TextView childText = (TextView) ConstraintLayout.getChildAt(i); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the view to `TextView` first, then call `setGravity`.

```
final View child = constraintLayout.getChildAt(i);
Object tag = child.getTag(R.id.tagId);
if (tag != null) {
    if (child instanceof TextView) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) child;
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    }
} else {}
```